# Replacing a long string containing special characters without using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have query. I need to replace the string below with another string in all the existing scripts, but the `sed -i` command is not at all working:

> ```
> sed: illegal option -- i Usage: sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...] sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
> ```

How can I do that?

Old String:

```
FCC_DATE=`sqlplus -silent "$USER_NAME"/\`openssl des -d -k pass<"$SCRIPT_PATH"/"$PASS_FILE"\`@"$SID"<<ENDSQL
```

New String:

```
FCC_DATE=`sqlplus -silent "$USER_NAME"/\"$SCHEMA_PASSWD"@"$SID"<<ENDSQL`
```

Comment: What is the full message for the `sed -i` invocation ? What is your system, and version of it ?

Comment: $ sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...] -----This is the message i am receiving please help!

Comment: What is your shell and which is its version ? Does it support the syntaxes `myvar=$(echo output of command)` and `${myvar/myold/mynew}` ?

Comment: NO Laurent its not supporting showing bad substitution error this is the output for uname -a :AIX fcnaswdbu1 1 6 00F6F2854C00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temporary file: `sed 'regex stuff' input > temp; mv temp input`

Comment: could you pls elaborate?

Comment: `sed -i` replaces "in place" : you don't have to care to separate input stream from output stream. What @JeLuF propose is to use the ancient way : `sed -e 's/yourold/yournew/' curr_file > temp_file ; mv temp_file curr_file` in a loop with `curr_file` evolving.

Comment: ok got that thanks Laurent,That I ahd fixed it my another issue now is i need to add two lines after a keyword and here is the command which works fine in Linux :                                                                               sed '/^get_system_date$/a\/flexapps/a2a_scripts/fc_common_code.sh \SCHEMA_PASSWD=`GetOraIDPWD fccint`' abc.txt...but in my unix box  it is showing as sed: Function /^get_system_date$/a\/flexapps/a2a_scripts/fc_common_code.sh \SCHEMA_PASSWD=`GetOraIDPWD fccint` cannot be parsed. ..Whashall I do for this..please suggest...

Comment: I don't have an old sed at hand, so the only things I can tell is that I like to explicit the `-e` in front of the sed script